# Formulário de contato não valida e não envia alguns campos

Tags: php, formulário

Olá, é minha primeira pergunta aqui! O problema é o seguinte...
Peguei um formulário na net e tentei adaptar para as minhas necessidades, porem os campos que criei (`$phone` e `$empresa`) não querem validar, tive de remover a validação destes campos, o formulário enviava mas estes campos chegam em branco eu sou mto noob em tudo, principalmente php :'(

---

Este é o formulário com a validação bugada x_x

[image: o formulário]

---

É assim que a mensagem chega, quando eu removo a validação de `$phone` e `$empresa`

[image: como eu recebo o email removendo a validação de phone e empresa]

---

HTML

```
<form id="contactform" action="chamadotecnico.php" name="contactform" method="post">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome">
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefone">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail">
    <input type="text" name="empresa" id="empresa" class="form-control" placeholder="Empresa">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="comments" id="comments" rows="6" placeholder="Descrição do problema técnico"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" value="SEND" id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right">Enviar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

// Verificação de endereço de email, não mexa!
function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$phone    = $_POST['phone'];
$empresa  = $_POST['empresa'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

if(trim($name) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Informe o seu nome.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Insira um endereço de e-mail.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Atenção! Você tem digitar um endereço de e-mail inválido, tente novamente.</div>';
    exit();
}

if(trim($phone) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Informe um telefone para contato.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($empresa) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Informe o nome da sua empresa.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($comments) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Informe a descrição do seu problema.</div>';
    exit();
}

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}

$address = "kaio.maia.so@gmail.com";
$e_subject = 'Chamado Técnico';

$e_body = "Nome: $name\r\nEmail: $email\r\nTelefone: $phone\r\nEmpresa: $empresa" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "Descrição do problema:\r\n$comments" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "Você pode entrar em contato $name via email, $email ou pelo telefone $phone";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<div id='success_page'>";
    echo "<h1>E-mail enviada com sucesso!</h1>";
    echo "<p>Obrigado <strong>$name</strong>, sua mensagem foi enviada, em breve entraremos em contato.</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';

}
```

---

[edit] JS que encontrei depois da ajuda do amigo Sanção

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $('#contactform').submit(function(){

        var action = $(this).attr('action');

        $("#message").slideUp(750,function() {
        $('#message').hide();

        $('#submit')
            .after('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader1" />')
            .attr('disabled','disabled');

        $.post(action, {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            website: $('#website').val(),
            subject: $('#subject').val(),
            comments: $('#comments').val(),
            verify: $('#verify').val()
        },
            function(data){
                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
                $('#message').slideDown('slow');
                $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
                $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                if(data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');

            }
        );

        });

        return false;

    });

});
```

Comment: Parece estar correto o código, depois de definir a variável `$phone`, dê um `echo $phone` e veja o valor que retorna.

Comment: Eu sugiro que você utilize algum plugin jQuery para fazer validação de dados. Isso evita de a validação ser feita no lado Servidor (PHP) e sim no lado Cliente (Browser, via JS, jQuery). Tem o **validate.js**. http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/. Isso é bom devido ao processamento mais rápido das páginas.

Comment: @DiegoSouza a validação exclusivamente no lado do cliente não é uma boa idéia, a validação também deve ser feita no servidor pois uma requisição por CURL pode burlar a validação no cliente. Desconfio que o problema é que o formulário é enviado por AJAX e o código JavaScript não está enviando os campos "personalizados" para o PHP, tem algum código javascript nessa página? seria bom adicionar aqui na pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código PHP parece correto. Tudo indica que seu formulário é enviado por AJAX, pois:

- existe um *spinner* na parte de baixo da imagem
- a mensagem de erro é gerada por um `echo` seguido de `exit` e deve ser incluída por javascript.

[image]

Em alguma parte da sua página deve haver algo parecido com

```
jQuery('#contactform').on('submit', function(e){
    // ...
})
```

Se houver algum instrução `.post()` ou `.ajax()` inclua esse código na sua pergunta. Acredito que essa função que não está enviando os campos telefone e empresa.

---

Você pode substituir o objeto JSON passado como segundo parâmetro de `$.post()` (abaixo) por `$(this).serialize()`, dessa forma todos os campos do formulário serão enviados para o PHP. Para mais informações acesse [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) (em inglês)

```
{
    name: $('#name').val(),
    email: $('#email').val(),
    website: $('#website').val(),
    subject: $('#subject').val(),
    comments: $('#comments').val(),
    verify: $('#verify').val()
}
```

Comment: REALMENTE!!! Encontrei um js como você falou, parece que ele é mesmo responsável por enviar os campos. Vou fazer os testes e ver se agora funciona, muito obrigado pela dica!!!

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar um `strip_tags` para remover alguma possivel tag `HTML` que possa ter vindo jundo:

```
$phone = (trim(strip_tags($_POST['phone'])));
```